# How to force mandatory input parameters in Entity Framework function import

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using database-first Entity Framework to access an existing database, and as part of that importing the stored procedures. The problem is that although the input parameters in the stored procedure are not optional, they get mapped as nullable.

This is the stored procedure declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[reverseGeocodeCity](
    @latitude FLOAT,
    @longitude FLOAT)
AS
--(snip)
```

And the function import mapping created this as the corresponding method:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<City> reverseGeocodeCity(
    Nullable<double> latitude, Nullable<double> longitude)
```

The stored procedure is not meant to accept `NULL` for any of its parameters. How can I force Entity Framework to map the input parameters as `double` instead of `double?`?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem we found a workaround for the problem. Just we wrap the double? property to double in our base entity; Hier is the code:

The Notmapped entity(Wrapper entity) it shall be used it from outside and the other one which will be stored and loaded from DB.

Inherited Entity code:

```
[NotMapped]
public double Longitude
{
  get
  {
    return this.FromNullable(this.longitude);
  }

  set
  {
    this.PropertyChange(ref this.longitude, value);
  }
}


[Column("Longitude")]
public double? LongitudeStored
{
  get
  {
    return this.longitude;
  }

  set
  {
    this.PropertyChange(ref this.longitude, value);
  }
}
```

---

Hier is base Entity code:

```
protected double FromNullable(double? value)
{
  return value.HasValue ? value.Value : double.NaN;
}


protected void PropertyChange(ref double? propertyValue, double newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
  this.PropertyChangeCore(ref propertyValue, double.IsNaN(newValue) ? (double?)null : (double?)newValue, propertyName);
}


protected void HandlePropertyCore(ref double? propertyValue, double? newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
  if ((newValue.HasValue || propertyValue.HasValue) &&    // If both are null than do not fire.
       ((!propertyValue.HasValue || double.IsNaN(propertyValue.Value))
       ^ (!newValue.HasValue || double.IsNaN(newValue.Value))   // If one of them is null or NaN then fire according to XOr rule.
       || Math.Abs(propertyValue.Value - newValue.Value) > double.Epsilon)) // If the are not the same than fire.
  {
    propertyValue = newValue;
    this.HandlePropertyCore(propertyName); // HERE YOU NEED JUST TO HANDLE DOUBLE PROPERTY
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to take care if you need double infinity you have to extend the code for Inf+ and Inf-.